# Archiving Xcode Project Errors

Tags: app-store-connect, archive, testflight, alamofire

I am trying to archive my project to upload it in TestFlight.
But I keep on getting these errors:

[image]

Can anyone help me on these errors, especially with the Alamofire issues?

Comment: Well what is your deployment target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please add missing icon as per suggested by xcode and then select your Project pbx file -> Targets -> General -> Deployment target. and select ios 8.0. Please also change it into plist file.